# How can I implement a Slack slash command to send something back to the workspace?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I don't want to expose my server to the Internet, but I have a Slack that it is interacting with.
How can I use the request URL of the slash command, to send a signal to a Slack app? I want users to use a slash command, so that the app/bot recognizes that somehow and writes into a private channel or something. My server is interacting with Slack through the app/bot, so I could read that input through checking that private channel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use slash commands without exposing an endpoint to the Internet.

The only alternative that does not require exposing your server to the Internet would be to use the [Real Time Messaging API](https://api.slack.com/rtm). It uses Websockets instead of HTTP. You can not use slash commands or any of the other interactive features like message buttons, but you can use chat. So e.g. your bot could listen to `!bot command` on a channel and respond to it.

Many chat bots are using the RTM API and there also are many libraries for it.

Technically you could also read and parse the message history for a channel through `conversations.history`, but I would make your bot very slow to react due to the API's rate limits.

Comment: I had already implemented something similar with `conversations.history` which turned out to be rather slow. This isn't a time critical application, but it's nice to get relatively fast feedback.  
I will look into the RTM API later this week, but this seems to be what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Assuming from your name that you plan to use Python: The official library has full RTM support: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient

Comment: Thanks, for the advice. I have already been using the python-slackclient for about 2 years now though, but I had the wrong idea about what the RTM API was. I'm currently refactoring my code, because it is using the old syntax (`slack.api_call('stars.add')` vs. `slack.stars_add()` though maybe I've missed that back then) and the (now legacy) token system to an slack app.

Comment: I implemented it and thanks for the advice! It's much faster and easier to deal with. (After setting up the app and RTM though, which turns out has some confusing documentation)